# Update AutoCAD 2015 custom drawing property fields from ArcGIS Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, geoprocessing, autocad

I need to update AutoCAD 2015 custom drawing property fields from a GIS point dataset shapefile format (in ArcGIS). I would like to do this for an AutoCAD template as project work starts.

I have tabular data for multiple sites as a point shapefile. I have created custom drawing property fields in AutoCAD 2015 that are currently copy and pasted from a spreadsheet output into CAD.

I know you can export Layer properties like color etc. from GIS into CAD file. Does anybody have experience on updating custom properties?